# Nginx decoding ampersand

Tags: nginx, encoding

We have canonical style URLs that we use for FB sharing. Facebook can scrape these pages for the info it needs to... these pages generate a specialized image to be shared by the user.

A user can specify a string to be displayed on this image.

Samwise Gamgee is encoded like

```
Samwise%20Gamgee
```

sam & frodo

```
sam%20%26%20frodo
```

The issue is when any one hits these URLS the ampersand `%26` is somehow being decoded by nginx

This...

```
www.example.com/path/Brian%26Bob%26Sally
```

Becomes...

```
www.example.com/path/Brian?Bob%26Sally
```

Not sure why but the only the first ampersand is being rewritten. Any ideas why this might be? Is Nginx even capable of this?

Comment: Please provide the nginx version and the config that might be related to this, like rewrites, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide those details. Really I am just curious is this possible for nginx to do? I read that it is a possible protection mechanism is this true?

Comment: Nginx could (and somtimes would) decode `%XX` to real character, but I can't imagine it replacing `&` with `?`.